# Two nested lists into dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

With two nested list:

```
list_1 = [[100, 90, 90, 85, 70], [100, 90, 90, 85, 80], [105, 100, 90, 90, 85]]
list_2 = [[1, 2, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4]]
```

I want to get the following result:

```
[{100:1,90:2,90:2,85:3,70:4},{100:1,90:2,90:2,85:3,80:4},{105:1,100:2,90:3,90:3,85:4}]
```

Code results:

```
>>> [[f'{a}:{b}' for a,b in zip(*z)] for z in zip(list_1, list_2)]
[['100:1', '90:2', '90:2', '85:3', '70:4'],
 ['100:1', '90:2', '90:2', '85:3', '80:4'],
 ['105:1', '100:2', '90:3', '90:3', '85:4']]
```

In my case I'm just printing it with the f'string and isn't dictionary with their keys, and values, however, the result is correct and is what I need!

Comment: Thanks this works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will do as you don't want a list of lists of strings, but a list of dicts:

```
[dict(zip(*z)) for z in zip(list_1, list_2)]
```

`dict(zip(*z))` is just a shorter way of doing the comprehension `{a: b for a, b in zip(*z)}`.

Comment: TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Comment: You have at some point used `dict` as a variable name and shadowed the built-in name. Never use `dict, list, set, tuple, etc` as variable names.

Comment: [{a:b for a,b in zip(*z)} for z in zip(list_1, list_2)]

this works perfectly fine

Comment: I know, but it is significantly longer. Take my advice to heart about shadowing built-ins ;-) to "unshadow", you can use `del dict`

Comment: You're right, that's why I got stuck, no idea when did I use dict I never do, but I do have a bad habit of naming them "dicto" so maybe I did create one variable with "dict". Thanks!